# How to ping the Boot2Docker machine (Guest machine) in Virtual box from outside the Host machine?

Tags: docker

I have run the selenium hub Docker image in Boot2Docker machine VM1, hosted inside my laptop H1.  I need to ping VM1 from another laptop H2.

Both H1 and H2 are in the same network. I am able to ping H1 from H2 and viceversa. Also, I am able to ping VM1 from H1. I am not able to ping VM1 from H2.

I have enabled NAT, Host-Only & Bridged adapters. Based on my reading, it is only the Bridged network that would resolve my issue. I am not sure if I am missing only some specific configuration in Bridged network to enable this.

Comment: you have to declare on H2 a dedicated gateway H1<@IP> to access VM network I think.

Comment: That gateway in H2, should be pointing to H1 IP or H1 Gateway?